# How to find the number of active connections with database in Rails application

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to find the active number of database connections in Active Record Rails.

Is there any method to find the number of connections?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

I'm not really sure if this number represents the actual number of active connections, but it gives me a number none the less:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.connections.size
```

Comment: What if there are multiple pool for multiple databases used?

Comment: This is the connections from the current process, not the connections in the db.

Answer (score 3):

Number of active connections
In development you can see the number of connections taken up by your application by checking the database.

```
bundle exec rails dbconsole
```

This will open a connection to your development database. You can then see the number of connections to your postgres database by running:

```
select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid() and usename = current_user;
```

Which will return with the number of connections on that database:

### count

5
(1 row)

see more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections